# When does a Python script in QGIS execute drawing of QgsRubberBand?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, drawing, qgsrubberband

I have a script which has an unrelated error after the `draw_polygon` function. I don't care about the error at the moment because I want to see the current results. For some reason my draw function doesn't work. My thought was that the drawing of `QgsRubberBand` happens after the succesful completion of a function?

```py
def draw_polygon(Polypoints):
    point = QgsVertexMarker(canvas)
    poly = QgsRubberBand(canvas, True)
    poly_points = []
    for feature in Polypoints:
        point.setCenter(QgsPoint(feature[0], feature[1]))
        point.setColor(QColor(255, 150, 0))
        point.setIconSize(20)
        poly_points.append(QgsPoint(feature[0], feature[1]))
    poly.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([poly_points]), None)
    poly.setColor(QColor(0, 150, 150))
    poly.setWidth(3)
```

I am using QGIS 2.18.

Comment: The function works correctly. You may be using unexpected `Polypoints`.